# Fitting multiple sliders to matplotlib interactive figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to create an interactive plot with multiple [sliders](https://matplotlib.org/api/widgets_api.html#matplotlib.widgets.Slider), but the output figure won't fit all of them inside a window.

Example using 25 sliders

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.axis('off')
axes = {'x' + str(i+1): plt.axes([.25,1 - i*.05,.65, 0.03]) for i in range(25)}
sliders = {label: Slider(ax, label, 0, 1) for label, ax in axes.items()}
plt.show()
```

[image]

The output figure needs to be adjusted to fit all sliders, regardless of how many of them are there.

Using `figsize` parameter didn't solve the problem, as it seems to only control the window size, thus scaling all sliders proportionally.

Comment: The strategy is the inverse: You need to set the axes coordinates to fit into the figure. Something along the lines of `[.25,1 - i/N,.65, 1/N*0.8] for i in range(N)`. Plus maybe some margin. Note that using subplots may be easier. `fig.add_subplot(N,1,i+1) for i in range(N)`.